# Duplicate keys in React, can't solve the issue. Encountered two children with the same key

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongoose

Error:

> Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `5e0611d77833da1668feade1`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

Here on this picture **https://prnt.sc/qgfymk** I have created 2 blogs. Delete button is working fine. I'm sending via axios to HTTP delete request using mongoose and MongoDB as my database.

But when I start to click on like button check what happens. **https://prnt.sc/qgg32o**
It removes my other blog post and copies one with the same name and id. The issue here is that I have different IDs but somehow when I press LIKE button it gives me another ID.

I'll give you code for both PUT request in backend and frontend for incrementLikes, I really don't know what is going on.

controllers/blogs.js  (backend)

```js
blogsRouter.put('/:id', async (request, response, next) => {

  const body = request.body
  const blogs = {
    title:body.title,
    author: body.author,
    url:body.url,
    likes: body.likes
  }

  try {
    const updatedBlog = await Blog.findOneAndUpdate(request.params.id, blogs, {
      new: true
    })
    response.json(updatedBlog.toJSON())
  } catch (exception) {
    next(exception)
  }
})
```

App.js

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Blog from './components/Blog';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm'
import BlogForm from './components/BlogForm'
import Notification from './components/Notification'

import loginService from './services/login';
import blogService from './services/blogs';


const App = () => {

  const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([])
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState(null)

  // states for blog creation
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('')
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState('')
  const [url, setUrl] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('effect')
    blogService
    .getAll()
    .then(response => {
      console.log('promise fulfiled')
      setBlogs(response.data)

    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('response', error.response)
      console.log('error')
    })
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    const loggedUserJSON = window.localStorage.getItem('loggedBlogUser')
    if (loggedUserJSON) {
      const user = JSON.parse(loggedUserJSON)
      setUser(user)
      blogService.setToken(user.token)
    }
}, [])

  //put request
  ***const incrementLike = id => {
    const blog = blogs.find(b => b.id === id)
    console.log('blog id', blog)
    const voteLike = {...blog, likes: blog.likes + 1}

    blogService
    .update(id, voteLike)
    .then(returnedBlog => {
      setBlogs(blogs.map(blog => blog.id !== id ? blog : returnedBlog))
    })
    .catch(error => {
      setErrorMessage(
        `Blog was already removed from server`
      )
      setTimeout(() => {
        setErrorMessage(null)
      }, 5000)
      })
  }***

  //login
  const handleLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    try {
      const user = await loginService.login({username, password})

      window.localStorage.setItem('loggedBlogUser', JSON.stringify(user))

      setUser(user)
      setUsername('')
      setPassword('')
      console.log('success')
    } catch (exception) {
        setErrorMessage('wrong credentials')
        setTimeout(() => {
          setErrorMessage(null)
        }, 5000)
        console.log('baaad')
    }
  }

  const deleteBlogId = (id) => {
    console.log('deleted blog')
    blogService
    .del(id)
    .then(response => {
      setBlogs(blogs.filter(blog => blog.id !== id))
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error.response);
    })
  }

  const handleCreateBlog = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const newBlogs = {
      title: title,
      author: author,
      url: url,
      date: new Date()
    }

    blogService
    .create(newBlogs)
    .then(returnedBlog => {
      setBlogs(blogs.concat(returnedBlog))
      setTitle('')
      setAuthor('')
      setUrl('')
      setErrorMessage(`${author} created new blog with name ${title}`)
      setTimeout(() => {
        setErrorMessage(null)
      }, 5000)
    })
  }


  const loginForm = () => {

    return (
      <div>
        <Notification message={errorMessage}/>
        <div>
          <LoginForm 
            username={username}
            password={password}
            handleUsernameChange={({target}) => setUsername(target.value)}
            handlePasswordChange={({target}) => setPassword(target.value)}
            handleSubmit={handleLogin}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }


  const handleTitleChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value)
    setTitle(event.target.value)
  }


  const blogForm = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <BlogForm
          title={title}
          author={author}
          url={url}
          handleTitleChange={handleTitleChange}
          handleAuthorChange={({target}) => setAuthor(target.value)}
          handleUrlChange={({target}) => setUrl(target.value)}
          onSubmit={handleCreateBlog}
        />

      </div>
    )
  }

  const handleLogout = async () => {
    window.localStorage.clear()
    setUser(null)
  }


  const logout = () => {
    return (
    <div><button type="reset" onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</button></div>
    )}

  const blogList = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Blogs</h2>
        <p>{user.name} logged in</p>
        {logout()}
        {blogs.map(blog => 
        <Blog 
        key={blog.id} 
        deleteBlog={() => deleteBlogId(blog.id)}
        blog={blog} 
        increment={() => incrementLike(blog.id)} />
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">

    {user === null ?

      loginForm() :
      <div>
        <Notification message={errorMessage}/>
        {blogForm()}
        {blogList()}
      </div> 
    }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Check the incrementLikes function. I think there is some kind of issue. Button for likies are in component called Blog.js

Blog.js

```
import React from 'react';


const Blog = ({blog, increment, deleteBlog}) => (
    <div>
        <button onClick={deleteBlog}>Delete</button> 
                {blog.title} 
                {blog.author} 
                {blog.likes} 
        <button onClick={increment}>Like</button>
    </div>
)

export default Blog
```

Comment: You may want to make a check of the value of `blog.id` after `{blogs.map(blog =>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there shouldn't be 2 blogs with the same ID you can fix the issue at hand by replacing the key from `blog.id` to the `index` of the post like this.

```
<div>
    <h2>Blogs</h2>
    <p>{user.name} logged in</p>
    {logout()}
    //change
    {blogs.map((blog,index) => 
    <Blog 
    //change
    key={index} 
    deleteBlog={() => deleteBlogId(blog.id)}
    blog={blog} 
    increment={() => incrementLike(blog.id)} />
    )}
</div>
```

I added `//change` to the lines I changed.

Comment: Ill try that now

Comment: I think there may still be an issue (likely on the backend) why it comes in duplicate, but this should solve the duplicate key error.

Comment: This seems to an issue with your response payload. Are all ids unique? Consider `key={`${index}_${blog.id}`}`

Comment: It solved error. I could also go key={blod.id + Math.random()} or anything similar. Yea problem is in the backend. Ill check it now.

Comment: There is no need to make the key anything complicated, it is only for react shadow dom reference, it isn't used or visible anywhere.

Comment: I solved error. It was backend with PUT request. If admin wants to delete post if not it can be showed as reference. Key error was in REACT but changing blog post to same when i press like was in backend PUT request. Thanks guys for ur help

Comment: Nice to hear you solved your problem, but one tip is I wouldn't use blog.id + Math.random() because it isn't performant and would be changing on every re-render, would follow the Neil idea at least... 

In case you want to read
https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: Anyone knows how to prevent user for liking blog post more then once? So if user already voted or pressed like button (+1) to prevent him for liking more then that. If u want we can go to chat room to continue this disscusion

Comment: To prevent a user from liking twice, you need to keep track of each user, either by loging them in or storing a cookie and saving to the database which posts they already liked. I actually did something similar in this small survey I created (https://www.vaccinateornot.com you can try i by voting and then trying to vote again), I store a cookie on the site and store to the database the user if he voted already and disable the vote button if he already did, it isn't fool proof as the user can delete the cookie and vote/like again but this is as far as I wanted to go on that one.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use something like uuid for this which will generate a unique ID.

```
import uuid from "uuid";

<>
  <h2>Blogs</h2>
  <p>{user.name} logged in</p>
  {logout()}
  {blogs.map((blog,index) => 
    <Blog 
      key={uuid.v4()} 
      deleteBlog={() => deleteBlogId(blog.id)}
      blog={blog} 
      increment={() => incrementLike(blog.id)} />
    )}
</>
```